# Android 7.1 app shortcuts

Tags: java, android

I am using the static shortcuts as follows (part of the shortcut.xml).

```
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="Noraml"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_t_voice_list"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/sp_audio_effect_PrDdefault"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/sp_audio_effect_PrDdefault">
    <intent
        android:action="com.app.shortcuts.IVRService"
        android:targetPackage="com.app.shortcuts"
        android:targetClass="com.app.shortcuts.AppService">
    </intent>
    <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
         here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
         they launch this shortcut. -->
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
</shortcut>
```

And in manifest file as follows.

```
<service
    android:name=".AppService"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.app.shortcuts.IVRService" />
        <action android:name="com.app.shortcuts.IVRRemoteService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But when I try to launch the app through shortcut, I am getting the "app is not installed" toast.

Are shortcuts only for activities? Or can we apply for services in the background without launching the app?

Answer (score 1):

Shortcuts can only launch activities as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html):

> Shortcuts provide users with quick access to activities other than an app's main activity in the currently-active launcher.

They cannot launch services.